# Error inflating class MaterialEditText

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to android development. Please help me in identifying the issue in my code. My code is getting into InflateException.
Please help me.

My code is existing with error related to MaterialEditText class and I have searched for the solution but till now didn't get the working solution.

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_vertical"
    tools:context="com.android.appgallery.quizworld.MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/wrap_login"
        />
       <RelativeLayout

           android:id="@+id/wrap_login"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:layout_margin="8dp"
           >

           <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
               android:id="@+id/info_login"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               xmlns:com.rengwuxian.materialedittext="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
               android:layout_margin="8dp"
               app:cardElevation="4dp">

           <LinearLayout
               android:padding="16dp"
               android:orientation="vertical"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               >

               <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:MaterialEditText
                   android:id="@+id/edtUser"
                   android:hint="User Name"
                   android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
                   android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                   android:textSize="24sp"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   app:met_baseColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                   app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
                   app:met_primaryColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                   app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
                   />

               <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:MaterialEditText
                   android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
                   android:hint="Password"
                   android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
                   android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                   android:textSize="24sp"
                   android:inputType="textPassword"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   app:met_baseColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                   app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
                   app:met_primaryColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                   app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
                   />

           </LinearLayout>
           </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_below="@id/info_login"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_sign_up"
                    android:text="Sign Up"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
                    android:text="Sign In"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>
       </RelativeLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">#1CB3BC</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

MainActivity

```
 package com.android.appgallery.quizworld;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.InflateException;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.android.appgallery.quizworld.BroadcastReceiver.AlarmReceiver;
import com.android.appgallery.quizworld.Common.Common;
import com.android.appgallery.quizworld.Model.User;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MaterialEditText edtNewUser,edtNewPassword,edtNewEmail; //For Sign Up
    MaterialEditText edtUser,edtPassword; //For Login

    Button btnSignUp,btnSignIn;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference users;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
try {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}catch(Exception e){
    //InflateException ex=new InflateException(parser.getPositionDescription()+" "+e.getMessage());
    InflateException ex=new InflateException(e.getMessage());
    ex.initCause(e);
    throw ex;
}

        registerAlarm();
        database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        users=database.getReference("Users");

        edtUser=(MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.edtUser);
        edtPassword=(MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
        btnSignIn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
        btnSignUp= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_up);

        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showSignUpDialog();
            }
        });

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                signIn(edtUser.getText().toString(),edtPassword.getText().toString());
            }

    });
    }

    private void registerAlarm() {

        Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,9);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,40);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);


    }

    private void signIn(final String user, final String pwd){
        users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if(dataSnapshot.child(user).exists()){
                    if(!user.isEmpty()){
                        User login=dataSnapshot.child(user).getValue(User.class);
                        if(login.getPassword().equals(pwd)){
                            Intent homeActivity=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Home.class);
                            Common.currentUser= login;
                            startActivity(homeActivity);
                            finish();

                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Wrong Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please enter your user name.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"User does not exist",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void showSignUpDialog(){

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Sign Up");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Please fill full information");
        LayoutInflater inflater=this.getLayoutInflater();
        View sign_up_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sign_up_layout,null);
        edtNewUser=(MaterialEditText) sign_up_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtNewUserName);
        edtNewPassword=(MaterialEditText) sign_up_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtNewPassword);
        edtNewEmail=(MaterialEditText) sign_up_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtNewEmail);

        alertDialog.setView(sign_up_layout);
        //Check for the icon
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_24dp);
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i){
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }

        });

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                final User user = new User(edtNewUser.getText().toString(), edtNewPassword.
                        getText().toString(), edtNewEmail.getText().toString());

                users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.child(user.getUserName()).exists())
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User already exists!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        else {
                            users.child(user.getUserName()).setValue(user);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User registration successful!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
            });

            alertDialog.show();

}
}
```

Error Snippet:

```
01-18 23:14:13.656 23773-23773/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-18 23:14:13.726 23773-23773/com.android.appgallery.quizworld D/LenovoAppIconTheme: ExtraResources;cleanCachedIcon;clear cache..
01-18 23:14:14.049 23773-23773/com.android.appgallery.quizworld W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 

/data/app/com.android.appgallery.quizworld-2/lib/arm
01-18 23:14:14.079 23773-23773/com.android.appgallery.quizworld D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping 

initialization.
01-18 23:14:14.095 23773-23773/com.android.appgallery.quizworld W/InstanceID/Rpc: Found 10014
01-18 23:14:14.102 23773-23773/com.android.appgallery.quizworld D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping 

initialization.
01-18 23:14:14.144 23773-23773/com.android.appgallery.quizworld I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 10298
01-18 23:14:14.144 23773-23773/com.android.appgallery.quizworld I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
01-18 23:14:14.163 23773-23773/com.android.appgallery.quizworld V/FA: Collection enabled
01-18 23:14:14.163 23773-23773/com.android.appgallery.quizworld V/FA: App package, google app id: com.android.appgallery.quizworld, 

1:778477946548:android:1b7a8c110537f112
01-18 23:14:14.163 23773-23773/com.android.appgallery.quizworld I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                                                        adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app 

com.android.appgallery.quizworld
01-18 23:14:14.163 23773-23773/com.android.appgallery.quizworld D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
01-18 23:14:14.210 23773-23773/com.android.appgallery.quizworld V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
01-18 23:14:14.212 23773-23773/com.android.appgallery.quizworld I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
01-18 23:14:14.213 23773-23773/com.android.appgallery.quizworld I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
01-18 23:14:14.219 23773-23792/com.android.appgallery.quizworld V/FA: Using measurement service
01-18 23:14:14.225 23773-23792/com.android.appgallery.quizworld V/FA: Connecting to remote service
01-18 23:14:14.297 23773-23773/com.android.appgallery.quizworld W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter 

android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, 

android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
01-18 23:14:14.306 23773-23773/com.android.appgallery.quizworld V/FA: onActivityCreated
01-18 23:14:14.472 23773-23773/com.android.appgallery.quizworld D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-18 23:14:14.473 23773-23773/com.android.appgallery.quizworld E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.android.appgallery.quizworld, PID: 23773
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 

ComponentInfo{com.android.appgallery.quizworld/com.android.appgallery.quizworld.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line 

#0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class MaterialEditText
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity

(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity

(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage

(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run

(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main

(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line 

#0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class MaterialEditText
                                                                                      at com.android.appgallery.quizworld.MainActivity.onCreate

(MainActivity.java:45)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6705)
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate

(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity

(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity

(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage

(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run

(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main

(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
                                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line 

#0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class MaterialEditText
                                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line 

#0: Error inflating class MaterialEditText
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 

"android.view.MaterialEditText" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.appgallery.quizworld-2/base.apk", zip file 

"/data/app/com.android.appgallery.quizworld-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.android.appgallery.quizworld-

2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.android.appgallery.quizworld-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file 

"/data/app/com.android.appgallery.quizworld-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.android.appgallery.quizworld-

2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.android.appgallery.quizworld-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file 

"/data/app/com.android.appgallery.quizworld-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.android.appgallery.quizworld-

2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.android.appgallery.quizworld-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file 

"/data/app/com.android.appgallery.quizworld-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.android.appgallery.quizworld-

2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.android.appgallery.quizworld-2/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass

(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView

(LayoutInflater.java:609)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView

(LayoutInflater.java:700)
                                                                                      at 

com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView

(LayoutInflater.java:717)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag

(LayoutInflater.java:785)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag

(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate

(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren

(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate

(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren

(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate

(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren

(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate

(LayoutInflater.java:861)
01-18 23:14:14.474 23773-23773/com.android.appgallery.quizworld E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren

(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate

(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate

(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate

(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                                      at 

android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView

(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                      at com.android.appgallery.quizworld.MainActivity.onCreate

(MainActivity.java:42)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6705)
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate

(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity

(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity

(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage

(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run

(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main

(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean @chefes as I can see I am using the right way.
Thanks for your reply